# python callback function returning None

Tags: python

I have a simple class that adds 2 nos. Before adding 2 nos I pass a helper function that appends 2 zeros and passes the result.

When I try to print the add_nos.provide(append_zeros) it always shows None.

```
def append_zeros(x,y):
    x = int(str(x) + '00' ) 
    y = int(str(y) + '00')
    print x+y
    return x + y

class Add_Nos():
    def __init__(self,input_array):
        self.input_array = input_array 

    def provide(self,callback):
        for each in self.input_array:
            x,y = each
            callback(x,y)

add_nos = Add_Nos([(1,2),(3,4)])            
print add_nos.provide(append_zeros)
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? You'll need to make `Add_Nos` subclass `object` else it creates an old-style class.

Comment: Also, the result from `callback(x, y)` is discarded. What do you want the return value to look like?

Comment: What do you want `print add_nos.provide(append_zeros)` to print?

Comment: I want the result to be 300 in the first instance and 700 in the next instance, kind of generate a iterator object.

Comment: Then you need to turn the `.provide` method into a generator.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but `provide` does not return anything.  In python, the default return type of any function is `None`, so implicitly printing `add_nos.provide(append_zeros)` will do the function call, and then `return None` behind the scenes.

One option you have is to return `self.input_array`:

```
class Add_Nos():
    def __init__(self,input_array):
        self.input_array = input_array

    def provide(self,callback):
        for each in self.input_array:
            x,y = each
            callback(x,y)

        return self.input_array
```

Note that you can also do `for x, y in self.input_array:` :)

Presumably, you actually want to be getting a new list out with the result of the computation.  In this case, this is an excellent candidate for a [list comprehension](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3):

```
def provide(self,callback):
    return [callback(x, y) for x, y in self.input_array]
```

This is a one-line equivalent of doing

```
def provide(self, callback):
    ret = []
    for x, y in self.input_array:
        ret.append(callback(x, y))
    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

The method add_nos.provide(self, callback) has no return statement, thus it returns nothing, which in python means that it returns `None`.

To avoid this, either add a return statement to provide() or simply call the method without print.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I want the result to be 300 in the first instance and 700 in the
>   next instance, kind of generate a iterator object.

So you simply need to turn the `.provide` method into a generator, and then call it appropriately. Like this:

```
def append_zeros(x,y):
    x = int(str(x) + '00') 
    y = int(str(y) + '00')
    #print x+y
    return x + y

class Add_Nos():
    def __init__(self,input_array):
        self.input_array = input_array 

    def provide(self,callback):
        for each in self.input_array:
            x,y = each
            yield callback(x,y)

add_nos = Add_Nos([(1,2),(3,4)]) 
for t in add_nos.provide(append_zeros):
    print t
```

**output**

```
300
700
```

---

That `append_zeros` function is a bit strange. Rather than converting the args to strings so you can append the zeros and then converting the results back to `int`s to do the arithmetic yu should simply multiply each arg by one hundred.

Also, you can make the `.provide` method a little more streamlined by using "splat" unpacking. And as `tyteen4a03` mentioned, in Python 2 your `Add_Nos` class ought to inherit from `object` so that you get a new-style class instead of the deprecated old-style class. So here's another version with those changes; it produces the same output as the above code.

```
def append_zeros(x, y):
    return x * 100 + y * 100

class Add_Nos(object):
    def __init__(self, input_array):
        self.input_array = input_array 

    def provide(self, callback):
        for each in self.input_array:
            yield callback(*each)

add_nos = Add_Nos([(1,2),(3,4)]) 
for t in add_nos.provide(append_zeros):
    print t
```